# How do I detect if I can open a browser with C

Tags: c, browser, cross-platform

So, I'm writing an app in C which requires that I open up a browser on the user's device to a specific URL.  To do this on Windows, I would use start; on Mac, I would use open; on Debian OS, I would use sensible-browser; and on Desktop environments that support xdg-open, I'd use that (All via system()).  First off, is this really the best way to open a browser via C?  Seems like there ought to be a simpler way.

My real issue is this what if this doesn't work?  How would I detect if the device can open a (GUI, JS enabled) web browser or if one of the above methods wouldn't work?

Something like

```
    if browser can be opened,
        open browser
    else do X
```

Is there a way to do this in C?  If so, what is it?

Comment: C provides `fork()`/`exec*()`, at least on UNIX and Mac. If `exec*()` failed the browser did not open.

Comment: However, if you could do something this does not necessarily mean it succeeded if you tried.

Comment: And whether the opened browser then actually is JS enabled is a totally different story anyways.

Answer (score 0):

No. There ain't one.

Okay, that's a bit short. The problem is that you're trying to run a hugely complex application and you're not even sure exactly what you want to run except that it's got to cover a few vaguely declared rules.

To be **certain** you have to actually specify the code you want to run. On Windows you might do this by using COM automation to link to a Internet Explorer and pass your URL to that (after checking the versions). Even on Windows you *cannot* be **certain** that "start" will start a browser of exactly the type you want.

The only way to be actually **certain** is to link with a browser engine that you know provides exactly what you want. This is quite a big job just to be **certain** and has obvious downsides so most people don't bother.

Comment: So you're saying I should try the actual browsers as opposed to something like open and like alk said try a fork and exec for firefox then chrome and so on?

Comment: No that's just ignoring the user preferences, ie: what if you find a copy of firefox V2 when the user wants Chrome? And even if you happen to find the right one it still doesn't mean the user hasn't disabled Javascript. If you want to be certain it will work as you want you have to supply the browser or use one you know, for sure, will or can be made to run as you want.

Comment: So, in short I should make the user decide it with a config file of some sort.  Thanks.